# html bootstrap navbar hamburger not working for dropdown menu

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

bootstrap navbar collapse not working. dropdown hamburger does not show
navbar-nav 's

Navbar
        
        
            
        
        
            
                Home
                About
                Contact
            
            
            
                
                Search

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72245286/edit) to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are having, including the relevant HTML. Also, why is this question tagged "bootstrap-4" when you are including the code for Bootstrap 5?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.